# MySQL table optimization for chat server

Tags: mysql, optimization

Hi i am making a server using Netty and MySQL.

My server's primary task is to record user's info, and chats.

I am very new to database and I am stuck at writing the schema for chats.

I need to record the chat room number, sender ID, reciever ID, content, and timestamp for each chat sent from the client.
I think about 50 chats for each chat room will be sent. And at least 100 chat rooms will be created daily.

I am thinking of making one table for every chat room created. However, this will make about 3000 tables every month. 
If I recorded all the chat rooms in one table, the table will be very long. I am guessing retrieving records from that table will take a lot of resources.

This part is where I am stuck. What is the normal practice when recording chats?

Comment: 3000 tables a month really is not much for a database. For your own sake, you could have a scheduled job which removes old data every now and then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine to have a database row for each chat room with foreign key relationships between messages, users and rooms.

Have a `rooms` table:

```
id, name, created
```

a `users` table:

```
id, username, password, created
```

a `messages` table:

```
id, room_id, user_id, message, time
```

then use some very simple JOINs in order to retrieve the data you want. For example, to retrieve the latest messages in a chat room:

```
SELECT u.username, m.message, m.time FROM messages
LEFT JOIN rooms r ON m.room_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN users u ON m.user_id = u.id
WHERE r.name = 'chatroomName'
AND m.time > lastPolledTime
```

replace `lastPolledTime` with the time that you last checked for messages, in order to remove duplicates.

Comment: That query has very bad performance as you are having a WHERE that spans 2 different tables. MySQL will only be able to use one index. So each query will pull ALL rows for chatroom "chatroomName" OR ALL rows from ALL rooms where time > lastPolledTime.